# How many vessels does it take to build an offshore wind farm?

Tags: wind-power, renewables

How many vessel-days does it take to build an offshore wind farm, per turbine or per megawatt? I notice that when an offshore wind farm is being built, there are quite a few vessels milling around: vessels for shuttling crew, surveying, heavy-lifting cranes, cable-layers, accommodation, pile-drivers.

Looking at all those vessels, and the total capacity, is there a typical number of vessel-days (i.e the number of days spent, per vessel, summed across all vessels) per unit of installation - per turbine, or per megawatt?

I've been watching the vessels move on [marinetraffic.com](http://marinetraffic.com/), and keeping an eye on the [4C Offshore register of vessels used on offshore wind farms](http://www.4coffshore.com/windfarms/vessels.aspx): even on completed wind farms such as the London Array, there's a lot of ongoing boat activity:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a part answer to your query as there seems to be a lot of challenges and variables that make it difficult to determine the total vessel hours.  Below is some detail that *approximates* the number of vessels per turbine.

The Crown Estate document [A Guide to an Offshore Wind Farm](http://www.thecrownestate.co.uk/media/211144/guide_to_offshore_windfarm.pdf) provides in detail the ships required from the planning to maintenance phases, and their running costs in both a handy table and diagram. Specifically, and relevant to the issue of vessel-days

> There is no single way to build and 
>   operate an offshore wind farm,

The main challenges being

> scale, water 
>   depth and distance from shore

These factors as well as conditions, seasonality etc would have a major effect on the amount of vessel-days, as you have described.  The document provides an approximation of the cost per 500 MW segment per ship for each stage, listed below:

**Survey stage:** Geophysical survey vessel; Ornithological and mammalian survey vessel

**Foundation stage:** Foundation 
installation vessel, Array cable-laying vessel

**Turbine and substation stage:**  Substation 
installation vessel, Turbine 
installation vessel

**Operation and Maintenance:** Maintenance vessels

The [European Offshore Wind](http://www.cleanenergypipeline.com/Resources/CE/ResearchReports/European_Offshore_Wind_INI.pdf) report suggests that the costs per vessel should decrease as new specialised wind-turbine-specific vessels are developed and used.